# how can i find xpath or CSS selector for only ''Total Cases'' in the following table (url =this https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ )

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried several types of XPath but none of those working as I want to

```
Xpath : //td[@class='sorting_1'], 
xpath: //tr[contains(@class,'even')]//td[@class='sorting_1'],
xpath : //tr[contains(@class,'odd')]//td[@class='sorting_1']

CSS: .even+ .odd .sorting_1 , .even .sorting_1
```

but the CSS selector does not work in the scrappy shell

can you please help me out of this situation??

Answer (score 1):

To get total cases by country, just use :

```
//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//td[contains(@style,'text-align:left;')][normalize-space()]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

To get the country names :

```
//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//td[contains(@style,'text-align:left;')][normalize-space()]
```

Output (219 lines):

[image: Tc]

Side note : `normalize-space` is used to filter "the ghost" line present in the table (no country name and a value of 721). Probably a leftover of and old "Diamond Princess" record.
EDIT : In fact 721 corresponds to the total number of cases on the two ships ( Diamond Princess and MS Zaandam)

**EDIT** : If you want to get the data for each country (ships and World included) located on the first tab only (213 nodes) :

```
//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//td[contains(@style,'text-align:left;')][parent::tr[not(@style="display: none")]]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

To exclude the ships (211 nodes) :

```
//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//td[contains(@style,'text-align:left;')][parent::tr[not(@style="display: none")]][not(./span)]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

To exclude ships and World  (210 nodes) :

```
//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//td[contains(@style,'text-align:left;')][parent::tr[not(@style="display: none")]][./a[@href]]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i am new in this sector. I have a question..  //table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//td[contains(@style,'text-align:left;')][normalize-space()]/following-sibling::td[3]  -- I inspect this in chrome but when i click the arrow it find '61643' in third position which is not in this tab.. i think its on another tab.. how can i find only this tab results.. and another question is - how can i exclude one or two element from my selection which has same selector??

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer. For the last question, you have to use specific predicates. What kind of items do you want to exclude ? Please provide an example of elements which have same selector.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try using this expression for xpath:

```
(//div[@class='maincounter-number']/span)[1]/text()
```

for css:

```
response.css('#maincounter-wrap:nth-child(7) span::text')
```